# Using protobuf-net in Silverlight application

Tags: protobuf-net, silverlight-5.0

I have successfully used protobuf-net.dll in console and WPF applications. However, when I tried using it in a Silverlight 5 application, I get the error message:

"you can't add a reference to protobuf-net.dll as it was not built against the Silverlight runtime. Silverlight projects will only work with Silverlight assemblies."

At the protobuf-net site (http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/), I see references to Silverlight compatibility issues, but could not find a Silverlight dll. How can I use protobuf-net in a Silverlight 5 application?

Thanks
Manish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Nuget package contain a Silverlight-specific build; if you add the reference via the Nuget package manager, it should set itself up correctly automatically.

If you are downloading the package from google-code, simply expand the .zip (r480, currently); it contains a "sl4" directory which contains the library built for Silverlight 4 (and above).

Comment: oh, I now see the sl4 folder, I should have guessed.

Answer (score 0):

In the souce distribution there is a project file

.\protobuf-net_Silverlight\protobuf-net_Silverlight.csproj

included in the distribution. I personally haven't worked with the silverlight stuff, but it might get you to where you need to be.

Comment: Thanks very much, I had not thought of looking at the source distribution. This pointer will be very helpful to learn more about the pbf-net implementation. For my current purposes, Marc's solution works well and unfortunately, I am not allowed to accept both answers.